# Customize extended view(Fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tv, leanback

I'm using a fragment that extends the Leanback Library's BrowseSupportFragment in my project

By the way, the default setting of BrowseSupportFragment is ListRow, and I want to show my data in VerticalGrid form instead of Row form whenever Category Header is changed.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/browse_dummy"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<androidx.leanback.widget.BrowseFrameLayout
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:id="@+id/browse_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.leanback.widget.BrowseRowsFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/browse_container_dock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.leanback.widget.ScaleFrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/scale_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </androidx.leanback.widget.BrowseRowsFrameLayout>

    <!-- Padding needed for shadow -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/browse_headers_dock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingEnd="50dp" />
</androidx.leanback.widget.BrowseFrameLayout>
```

The settings for the layouts shown here are already done in the library.

Can I modify this layout shape within this situation?

Or should I use some other way without using this?

Comment: Have you tried using `VerticalGridSupportFragment`?

Comment: It's my fault for checking your answer so late.. After a long thought, I made a similar composition through the method of configuring two VerticalGridFragments. My mistake for pursuing too simple. 
thanks for the reply

Comment: No problem! You may add your implementation as an answer if you think that might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of this question. I have found the answer to this question. If you ever need this, feel free to use it

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:name="com.your.package.YourFragmentHeader"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp" />

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
    android:name="com.your.package.YourFragmentRight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/header"
    />
```

Layout just implements like this

```
MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment(categoryID);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, mainFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And you can programmatically render a Fragment as a dynamic grid of grouped lists, like BrowseSupportFragment .